# Executing the openssl command with the c system function is different from executing the openssl command output on the terminal

Tags: c, openssl

I'm using MacOS/10.13

My code on terminal:

```
echo -n this | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K 0 -iv 0 -base64
```

c code:

```
int main(){
   system("echo -n this | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K 0 -iv 0 -base64");
}
```

Running ScreenShot

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not see a valid reason for the differing behaviour. You should double-check that you are really running the code that you present here

Comment: What shell are you using? `system()` uses `sh -c` to run the command.  [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) "shall behave as if a child process were created using `fork()`, and the child process invoked the `sh` utility using `execl()` as follows: `execl(<shell path>, "sh", "-c", command, (char *)0);`"

Comment: Interesting... Mac OS X running /bin/sh prints "-n test" when calling "echo -n test". Use /bin/echo in your source to get the correct behaviour

Comment: I am really puzzled of this... /bin/bash and /bin/sh are different binaries, but have exactly the same version string (GNU bash, version 3.2.57...). Size is similar, but not identical. The echo builtin behaves very differently. Probably some kind of compatibility-foo, but it is a very bad idea doing it this way, apple

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to post text. Specifically, now integrity of your question relies on availability of an external site: if imgur goes down (or is unavailable for some other reason), your question loses an essential part of it.

Comment: @Andrew Henle I'm using /bin/zsh

Comment: @Ctx I'm sure that I'm really running the code cause I just ran that again and it got the same result......sad

Comment: @intelfx  Sorry about making you feel unclear.But I don't know other methods to show the problem except for using screenshots.

Comment: @Jenny I gave you the answer above... Didn't you read the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `echo` command has the problem that its behavior is not portable between different shells or environments. It is better to use [`printf`](https://ss64.com/bash/printf.html) instead, which is portable. In your case, replace the `echo -n` statement with `printf`, resulting in the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    system("printf this | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K 0 -iv 0 -base64");
}
```

Building and running:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test
gc8X3os/mFxDE73AebmweQ==
```

as desired.